# How to set filetypes that YCM recognizes as C++ files

Tags: c++, vim, youcompleteme

I've looked through all YouCompleteMe's documentation (for vim) but i can't seem to find the option to set which file extensions it recognizes as C++ files. I'm trying to change it so that I have C++ semantic completion in .h files. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, used vim's builtin settings to force vim to detect .h files as cpp by adding the following line to my .vimrc

au BufRead,BufNewFile *.h set filetype=cpp

Seems YCM now uses cpp completion for .h files :)